# Why do the print sequence of this code does not work as I expected?

Tags: c++

I have a class System (ISystem as interface), which holds a Controller, either ControllerA or ControllerB. System can switch controller by calling stateChanged:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class ISystem{
public:
    virtual void stateChanged(int state)=0;
};

class Controller{};

class ControllerA : public Controller{
public:
    ControllerA(ISystem* system){
        system->stateChanged(1);
    }
};

class ControllerB : public Controller{
public:
    ControllerB(ISystem* system){}
};

class System : public ISystem{
protected:
    Controller* controller;
public:
    System(){this->controller=NULL;}
    void stateChanged(int state){
        if(controller!=NULL){
            delete controller;
        }
        switch(state){
            case 0:
            controller=new ControllerA(this);
            printf("state 0 with ControllerA\n");
            break;
            case 1:
            controller=new ControllerB(this);
            printf("state 1 with ControllerB\n");
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

In the main,I create a System and set it to state 0, then it should create ControllerA first, and then in ControllerA call stateChanged(1) to switch to ControllerB:

```
int main(){
    System system;
    system.stateChanged(0);
    return 0;
}
```

so I expect the output is:

```
state 0 with ControllerA
state 1 with ControllerB
```

but the result output sequence is :

```
state 1 with ControllerB
state 0 with ControllerA
```

why would that happen?

Comment: If you don't see it, step through it with a debugger.

Comment: Your code can be reduced to: `void foo() { printf("in foo()\n"); } int main() { foo(); printf("calling foo ...\n"); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you enter this:

```
case 0:
controller=new ControllerA(this);
printf("state 0 with ControllerA\n");
break;
```

It first calls the c-tor of `A`, which calls this:

```
system->stateChanged(1);
```

Which in turn does this:

```
case 1:
controller=new ControllerB(this);
printf("state 1 with ControllerB\n");
break;
```

## Warning

But that essentially means that `delete` on the `A` object is called *from inside of its constructor* and that sounds kind of wrong. You might want to rethink this idea (starting with "raw pointers shouldn't ever own resources" guideline).

Answer (score 0):

You create the new `ControllerA` before outputting your message. Maybe you meant:

```
void stateChanged(int state){
    if(controller!=NULL){
        delete controller;
    }
    switch(state){
        case 0:
        printf("state 0 with ControllerA\n"); //print before creating
        controller=new ControllerA(this);
        break;
        case 1:
        printf("state 1 with ControllerB\n"); //ditto
        controller=new ControllerB(this);
        break;
    }
}
```

Although you should be using `std::cout` rather than `printf` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You call to `system.stateChanged(0);` calls the constructor of ControllerA which calls `system.stateChanged(1);`.

The constructor of ControllerB does nothing and so you end up printing `"state 1 with ControllerB\n"` going back up into the first `stateChanged` call and print `"state 0 with ControllerA\n"`there.